# SQL Server - sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats not receiving statistics from view

Tags: sql, sql-server, usage-statistics

In order to get an overview of usage statistics on our tables within SQL Server we have created a query which retreives usage statistics from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats.

The query is as follows:

```
Select 
    iif(t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE', 'Table', 'View') as 'Type'
    , t.TABLE_CATALOG
    , t.TABLE_SCHEMA
    , t.TABLE_NAME
    , max(tst.LastReferenced) as 'LastReferenced'
    , getdate() as 'Date'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
LEFT JOIN (
                        SELECT 
                        tst.object_id
                        ,(SELECT Max(v) FROM (VALUES (tst.Last_user_update), (tst.Last_user_seek), (tst.Last_user_scan), (tst.Last_user_lookup)) AS value(v)) as 'LastReferenced'
                        FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats tst
                    )tst on OBJECT_NAME(tst.object_id) = t.TABLE_NAME
WHERE t.TABLE_NAME not like ''_TMP%''
GROUP BY
    t.TABLE_CATALOG
    , t.TABLE_SCHEMA
    , t.TABLE_NAME
    , t.TABLE_TYPE
```

However, for one of our views, when executing the following actions on the table:

- Selecting first 1000 rows
- Filtering on values

No usage statistics are passed to our sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats table. For other views in the same database and exeucting the same actions these statistics are passed.

There has been no server restart or any clearance of these table due to which the statistics might have been reset. Also, we check these statistics every 15 mins so this should not be an issue.

Also, the join from sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats to INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES delivers a null value as this specific view is not contained at in the dm_db_index_usage_stats table.

**Questions**

1. How can it be that for this specific view no usage statistics are processed?
2. Is there a way to access these statistics or make them available to the sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats table?

Looking forward to your wisdom :)

Comment: Are they indexed views or standard views?

Comment: They are all standard views

Comment: I think you'd better check that. If they are not indexed they cannot have a row in `dm_db_index_usage_stats`, only the base table will show

Comment: Why is it then that other non schema bound views and non-indexed views (at least not code indexed) are visible in these usage statistics table?

Comment: No idea, cannot replicate on my machine. When I create a new table, do not select from it, create a view on it and select from that, I only get results in `dm_db_index_usage_stats` from the base table. If it doesn't have an index, how can it have index usage stats? Non-indexed views don't actually physically exist

Comment: Might it be that as this specific view uses two different databases and the others do not it cannot systematically create a indexed view. Thus, in some cases SQL will create its own index on the view on runtime?

Comment: No, there is no such thing as a runtime or automatic index. I suggest you check that they really are views and that they are not indexed, by using `select v.name, i.name, case when i.type = 1 then 'clustered' else 'nonclustered' end from sys.views v left join sys.indexes i on i.object_id = v.object_id` if these are not null then you have an indexed view. Or putting another way: every row in `dm_db_index_usage_stats` should have a matching row in `sys.indexes` (matching by `object_id` and `index_id`)

Comment: This is giving me the following output for the relevant columns:

**v.name** = table_name
**i.name** = all NULL
**All tables non-clustered**

Meaning that there are no clusters but indexing is then done on the base tables of these views?

Comment: Sorry no there is no index at all on them, so you can ignore the `nonclustered`. Try this one `select o.name, o.type_desc, ius.user_seeks, i.name indexName, case when i.type = 1 then 'clustered' when i.type > 1 then 'nonclustered' end from sys.objects o join sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats ius on ius.object_id = o.object_id left join sys.indexes i on i.object_id = ius.object_id and i.index_id = ius.index_id` I would expect there to be no nulls now, in other words all rows in `dm_db_index_usage_stats` match `sys.indexes`

Comment: Strangely enough the columns for indexName and index are all still null. 

Even more strange is that the only view that is not found back in dm_db_index_usage_stats is also not present in this list :o